# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/abc/abcsdk/Manifest$permission;

Tags: android, android-manifest, obfuscation, android-library

We have to ship a lib project and want to with hold the source code. 
So i did the following steps.

1. Took appengine.jar from /bin and placed it in /libs
2. deleted source folder.

Now when i include this project in an android app, everthing is fine when during compilation but when i run the application, I get the following error:

```
[2014-01-28 21:40:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/abc/abcsdk/Manifest$permission;
[2014-01-28 21:40:40 - DemoApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/abc/abcsdk/Manifest$permission;
```

I even added this lib manually via configure build path but i still get this error.

Could someone please help me figure out the issue?

Comment: someone please? i am really stuck

Comment: someone please......i am at a deadend

Comment: someone please......call for help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting your bin directory and running a clean solution.

I have seen and encountered this before.. also try checking your buildpath and make sure your bin is not included in your build path.

if this doesn't work try this:

Right click on the Project Name
Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Java Build Path, go to the tab Order and Export

Unchecked your .jar library

Comment: not working...the issue is that since the package name is the same for the jar and the project, hence it is complaining.

Comment: hmm you definitely have two copies somewhere..

try this? grep -r YourOffendingClassName YourApp | grep jar